# Header of viewcontroller doesn't fit

Tags: ios, swift

So the original setup of the app that I inherited has the navigation bar set like so (this is in my AppDelegate):

```
private func configureNavigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) {
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo-white"))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    let center = (navigationController.topViewController?.view.frame.width)! / 2.0 - 44

    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: center, y: 0, width: 88, height: 44))
    imageView.frame = titleView.bounds
    titleView.addSubview(imageView)


    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.navBackground
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().addSubview(titleView)
}
```

This creates the nav bar across every view controller correctly with the image in the center, however I have some new functionality that needs to be on top of everything, and this logo file - logo-white - is still showing up over top.

That's the real problem I want to solve - so if my attempted solution below is wrong, let me know and tell me the correct way.

Anyway, I tried commenting out the code above in my AppDelegate, and putting it in the specific viewcontrollers that I need it for

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo-white"))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    let center = (navigationController!.topViewController?.view.frame.width)!// / 2.0 - 44

    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: center, y: 0, width: 88, height: 44))

    imageView.frame = titleView.bounds
    titleView.addSubview(imageView)

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

However this doesn't work - I can either get the logo to show up on the left side of the screen, or slightly off of center, but never center.

I am guessing that this is because the bar has a back button and a little settings icon as well on either side.

So, how do I do this correctly?

Is there a way to make it so that something can cover the logo? Is the solution to move it into my individual view controllers?

Here's a picture of the overlap here. The logo, "Pinyada" should not be covering this up at all - this is a third party library that should be on top of everything.

[image: Logo on top of the third party library that is covering everything else]

[image: When I try to put the header setup in the viewcontroller, the image is unbalanced]

Comment: no need to set imageView's frame when you set it as a titleView

Comment: FWIW your question would be easier to follow if you add screenshots

Comment: Absolutely. I'll include one.

Comment: I'm confused exactly how you want it to look. Can you mock up a screenshot for the way you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo-white"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 88, height: 44)
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

If you have `navigationItem.titleView` , another titleview is not necessary.

Sometimes, if you need a much more precise control of the titleView, you can add a customTitleView. Add the following codes in the viewController and you can get what you want.

```
let  imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo-white"))

private func addTitleView(){
    let nbar =   (navigationController?.navigationBar)!
    let width = nbar.frame.width
    imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect.init(x: (width - 88) / 2.0 , y: 0, width: 88, height: 44)
    nbar.addSubview(imageView)
}

private func removeTitleView(){
     imageView.removeFromSuperview()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    addTitleView()
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    removeTitleView()
}
```

BTW, `UINavigationBar.appearance().addSubview(titleView)`

This method will result in all navigationBar with the same titleView, which is not what you want.

Comment: Hrm, no this still leads to an image that is not centered. It's left-ish relative to the center. And that's true no matter what of the CGRect parameters I modify.

Comment: It may depends on what your image is. Maybe the image is not symmetrical

Comment: No, the image is symmetrical, just checked. This is quite weird.

Comment: Is there anyway I can just... override this image set in the app delegate, while inside of a view controller? That sounds messy, but my impression is that the initial developer who wrote this did this a bit kludgy in the first place

Comment: Yes. you may start a new storyboard.

Comment: Are the image proportions exactly 44x88? Try using a different content mode, for example `.center`

Comment: No, it appears not. The logo file is much larger than 44x88. I'll test with the different content mode as well. Should I be doing this in the individual viewcontroller and take it out of AppDelegate (where the previous developer put it)?

Comment: Maybe that's the reason. Just using a limited size may help you.

Comment: Hrm, I tried using a limited size with .center and all it did was make the image off-center. Whenever I try to set the image inside of the view controller, as opposed to the AppDelegate, it is unbalanced.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

One of the other modifications to my header was taking up too much space. I made it smaller and the image fits perfectly.

I moved all of the code generating the header out of the AppDelegate and into my navigation protocol, where I then popped it into each and every viewcontroller.